# Finding out the cause of the Hard Fault in lpc1788

Tags: embedded, arm, lpc

I have been developing a firmware that has a heavy GUI library ported on [lpc1788](http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers/cortex_m3/LPC1788FET208.html). I am using a 32 MB SDRAM for processing the fonts and images and a NAND flash to store the binaries of the font and bmp's, along with the device configuration data.
I have disable the Usage Fault, MemManage fault and Bus Fault. So sometimes when something goes wrong with any GUI function, the execution goes in Hard Fault. Now, the library that I have used for GUI is [emWin](http://www.segger.com/emwin.html) and I have no means to know what function caused the Hard Fault. If the NAND flash is corrupted and the library tries to fetch anything to display, say a background image, then it goes in hard fault. I can handle such a situation, because I know for sure (by means of some code implementation with flags) that my NAND flash is corrupted and I need to reprogram the binaries into it, because if I don't, whenever the device is booted up, it will go in hard fault.
But, if some other routine causes the Hard Fault, then I actually should not reprogram the entire flash allover again.
So, if I know what caused the Hard Fault, I would be able to modify the handler accordingly deciding on whether I need to reprogram it or simply modify some parameters and carry on with the last know configuration.

Is there a way to determine what function caused the Hard Fault, run-time? Even the address would be enough. Can this be done?

Comment: Note that the answer is generic to any Cortex-M3/4 device - you'd get a wider audience perhaps if you weren't unnecessarily specific about the particular chip. In fact you probably needn't have asked; Googl "cortex-m hard fault" for example.  There's a short simple question in here amongst a great deal of irrelevant waffle. I think the last paragraph is it delete the rest. Although one of the irrelevant parts, emWin is the opposite of a "heavy GUI library", Qt is a heavy GUI library.

Comment: Can you get it to fail with gdb connected via SWD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement a hard fault handler that reports the stacked registers.  The PC register will indicate the execution address at which the exception occurred.

An example can be found [here](http://blog.frankvh.com/2011/12/07/cortex-m3-m4-hard-fault-handler/), though the use of `printf` in the example is probably ill-advised; you'd want something that wrote unbuffered direct to the UART I'd suggest - the system is already broken - the less code needed to get the diagnostic out the better.  The similar solution [here](http://www.freertos.org/Debugging-Hard-Faults-On-Cortex-M-Microcontrollers.html) simply copies the values to variables and requires you to set a breakpoint in your debugger to inspect them.

To see the code at the reported PC address, either consult your compiler's map and or list output files, or enter the address directly into the PC register in your debugger.